# Can I define style in CSS for input with attribute selectors and a class also?

Tags: jquery, css

Can I define style in CSS for input with attribute selectors and a class also?

```
input[type=text].focus
```

The above css does not work. But is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `input[type="text"].focus` (with quotes around attribute value)

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dn3wU/

Anyway also that specific unquoted value should work, [as stated here](http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes)

> A valid unquoted attribute value in CSS is any string of text that is not the empty string, consists of escaped characters and/or characters matching /[-_\u00A0-\u10FFFF]/ entirely, and doesn’t start with a digit or two hyphens or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dn3wU/1/):

```
input[type=text]:focus
```